# How can I handle IOException when Kafka is down?

Tags: java, exception, apache-kafka

I am trying to publish message, and Apache Kafka is down.
How should I handle an emergency situation like this?

KafkaProducer::send() method doesn't throw any exceptions that could be handled. Producer swallows them and logs errors instead, so I get flooded with messages like this, and everything hangs until Kafka gets connected again.

```
2014-03-31 09:38:23.752 ERROR o.a.kafka.common.network.Selector - Error in I/O: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:205) ~[kafka-clients-0.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:212) [kafka-clients-0.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:150) [kafka-clients-0.8.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
```

Comment: You happen to find a solution to this? It's been a small burden for an auditing app I'm working on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `get()` on the future returned by [Producer.send(...)](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord)), or if you don't want to block your code, pass a [callback](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord,%20org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback)).

`try {
  producer.send(new ProducerRecord("mytopic", key, value))
     .get(); // block until acknowledged
} catch(Exception e) {
  // handle message wasn't acknowledged
}`

Comment: I'm sure it wasn't: callbacks and futures were [added](http://www.confluent.io/blog/whats-coming-in-apache-kafka-0-8-2/) in the "new" producer client in December 2014.  But now we have an answer!

Answer (score -2):

I think the one thing you could do is to use a try/catch to log all `Throwable` in your producer code.

Comment: The KafkaProducer swallows the errors as pivovarit said. See https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/7130da90a9ee9e6fb4beb2a2a6ab05c06c9bfac4/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/Sender.java#L124

Comment: Or rather https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.2/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/network/Selector.java#L276 for the exact error.